# How to add tooltips to button define behind with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, tooltip

I defined buttons in a for loop in behind with C#

```
protected void GenTable()
{
    for (int r = 0; r < 100; r++)
    {
        var buttonField = new ButtonField
        {
            ButtonType = ButtonType.Button,
            Text = "Model",
            CommandName = "Display",
        };
        Model.Columns.Add(buttonField);
        break;
    }      
}​
```

How can I add tooltips to these buttons?
I trid to add tooltip or title into the for loop but doesn't work.
Can anyone help me fix it? Thanks

Comment: Are you constructing this `ButtonField` for a gridview? If so you can do it in `RowDataBound` event.

Comment: Yes! I'm constructing this buttonField for a gridview. But I didn't quite understand RowDataBound, is that in HTML part? Thanks

Comment: @RahulSingh Do you mean by this? <asp:GridView ID="DataDetailGrid" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="true" OnRowDataBound="add tooltip here?">

Comment: No you will have to write an event handler for `RowDataBound`, find the button there and then add ToolTip. Refer some good tutorial.

Comment: @RahulSingh    Is there any example that I can learn from.. i'm really a beginner in web developing. Appreciate your patience so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option to do what you want with a [`System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

However, there is a possible workaround. You can set its `Text` property as it was an `HTML`, e.g

```
<asp:ButtonField Text="<span title='My beautiful button'>Model</span>" />
```

---

**Update**

Since you're setting the `Text` through C#, it seems that they unescape the `<`, `>` characters.

So, another workaround is by using the `RowDataBound` event. E.g: Given a GridView like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" runat="server">
```

With the first column as follows:

```
<asp:ButtonField Text="Model" />
```

You can use the event `ItemDataBound` event below:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        (((System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0])).ToolTip = "My beautiful button";
    }
}
```

Note: change the `Cells[0]` to the index of the column you want, so if you have created 100 columns, and want to show 100 tooltips (like your code does), you must loop there and change to `Cells[i]`.

Comment: It doesn't work. the whole "<span title='Nice button'>Model</span>' thing shows in the button

Comment: I've just tested here, and it's showing, not sure what you're doing wrong. Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Can you send your test code to me? both the html part nad the C# part.

Comment: Thanks! you can post it here or send to my email niutong@email.wustl.edu

Comment: I can not find this <asp:ButtonField Text="Model" /> In my HTML. The only buttonfield I generate is in C# ModelCatFieldsGrid.Columns.Add(buttonField);

Comment: <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Model"></div>    
                
                <asp:GridView ID="DataDetailGrid" runat ="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="true"> 
                

                </asp:GridView> This is the only grid view I have about that model button